# Shopify Ajax Cart : how to user Shopify.updateCartFromForm?

Tags: ajax, shopify

i am new to shopify theme development ,i am looking to update cart using ajax call. can any one please specify how to make a call to 
function Shopify.updateCartFromForm? or what its prototype i mean required arguments

Comment: You need to read the AJAX API here:https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/getting-started/using-ajax-api

Comment: You can also have a look at this plugin https://cartjs.org/ and read over the API docs as @drip has mentioned too.

Comment: thanks for reply its worked for me